# How to group more row have same value into one row in django

Tags: python, django

```
    {'item__sale_code': None, 'order__customer__code': 'CLC', 'outstanding_quantity': '5.00', 'order__currency__name': 'YEN', 'original_amount': '92500.00', 'order__customer__name': 'Cloud Customer', 'local_amount': Decimal('0')}
    {'item__sale_code': 'None', 'order__customer__code': 'CLC', 'outstanding_quantity': '3.00', 'order__currency__name': 'YEN', 'original_amount': '36000.00', 'order__customer__name': 'Cloud Customer', 'local_amount': Decimal('0')}
{'item__sale_code': 'None', 'order__customer__code': 'SGC', 'outstanding_quantity': '10.00', 'order__currency__name': 'YEN', 'original_amount': '66000.00', 'order__customer__name': 'SCG Customer', 'local_amount': Decimal('0')}
```

I have a tuple list in django. Now I want to group two rows that have the same Customer into one row and calculate sum of `outstanding_quantity` and `original_amount`. It should look like this:

```
{'item__sale_code': 'None', 'order__customer__code': 'CLC', 'outstanding_quantity': '8.00', 'order__currency__name': 'YEN', 'original_amount': '128500.00', 'order__customer__name': 'Cloud Customer', 'local_amount': Decimal('0')}
{'item__sale_code': 'None', 'order__customer__code': 'SGC', 'outstanding_quantity': '10.00', 'order__currency__name': 'YEN', 'original_amount': '66000.00', 'order__customer__name': 'SCG Customer', 'local_amount': Decimal('0')}
```

This is my code python.py:

```
my_list = my.values('order__customer__code', 'order__customer__name', 'order__currency__name',
                                         'item__sale_code') \
            .annotate(Sum('outstanding_quantity')) \
            .annotate(Sum('original_amount'))
```